# iOS Safari not working with $_SERVER["QUERY_STRING"] to pass parameters to embedded iframe source

Tags: php, ios, url, iframe, parameters

Page 'A' is a .php page which contains an embedded iframe from an external source.

I need to append Query String Parameters to the iFrame source URL in order to return different database results to the end user, from a third-party database product.

I have used `<?php echo $_SERVER["QUERY_STRING"]; ?>` to do this, thusly:

```
<iframe width="100%" height="1000" frameborder="0" scrolling="auto"
src="http://www.booking-manager.com/wbm2/page.html?<?php echo $_SERVER["QUERY_STRING"]; ?>">
</iframe>
```

Page A:

```
http://www.scotsail.co.uk/mobile/param_test.php
```

Examples of parameters I might pass:

```
?companyid=1677&setlang=en&view=SearchResult&filteredcountries=GR&filter_duration=7&setCurrency=GBP&customCssPath=http://www.scotsail.co.uk/mobile/styles/wbm.css&flags=1
```

Full link then would then be:

```
http://www.scotsail.co.uk/mobile/param_test.php?companyid=1677&setlang=en&view=SearchResult&filteredcountries=GR&filter_duration=7&setCurrency=GBP&customCssPath=http://www.scotsail.co.uk/mobile/styles/wbm.css&flags=1
```

**This DOES work for** Firefox 46.01 and IE11: i.e. page is returned, iframe source clearly receiveing the parameters and displaying expected results.

**This DOES NOT work** for iPhone 6 Plus, iPad 3 or desktop versions of Chrome and Safari: i.e. page is returned,  iframe source is receiving something (companyid=XXX) but the iframe source shows an empty results set.

I have spent hours testing repeatedly the exact same link across the different browsers and devices, differing commbinations of the parameters, looking online - I cannot figure out what on earth is going on. Granted I have been at my keyboard coming up for 20 hours now so hoping i'm being dense.

**Questions**

Can you replicate this behaviour?
Do you know why this behaviour is being experienced?
Can you suggest a fix or workaround?

I really hope I am being incredibly dumb and missing something stupid.   Thank-you in advance for your help.

Regards

Spinnaker

**UPDATE - have tried `<?php echo http_build_query($_GET); ?>` also  but still get same weird effect with some browsers working and some others not....pulling my hair out...**

Comment: `$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']` is processed in PHP on the server, it has nothing to do with the browser.

Comment: Thank-you for the reply.    Yes i'm aware of that, but given my efforts to eliminate possible sources, on the face of it the clearly differing behaviour with different browsers was all that was / is left (!)

Comment: What do you see when you "View Source" on the browsers that don't work?

Comment: Hi Barmar, I tried this with all of them.   All of them show a perfect and valid echo print of the query string immediately after the iframe source url, in such a way that should work correctly.    Really need help with this !!

Answer (score 0):

Since your query string contains special characters, it needs to be URL-encoded. Instead of inserting the query string directly, use `http_build_query($_GET)`. This will properly escape everything. So change it to:

```
<?php echo http_build_query($_GET); ?>
```

Comment: Thanks so much for taking the time to write this answer - I have tried this and it seems to work in a similar way to the method I implemented first, unfortunately it produces the same results as the original problem, but it's much appreciated as I hadn't thought about the control characters. Thanks